# Matching a number sequence in grep

Tags: linux, regex, grep, syntax

So I'm trying to match a year number sequence with grep and this should be easy. I'm just a bit stumped that my simplistic regex isn't working.

What I'm doing is running a tool which archives some files but it needs to check for the date of the file to put it in the correct directory. I already have properly formatted input which comes to me as:

```
<span class='t-d'>1994-Oct-28</span>
```

This is just one example, when I have this I want to grab just the 1994 part of it and use this to continue archiving to the correct year. I was assuming something like this would be sufficient:

```
grep -o '[0-9]{4}'
```

But this doesn't seem to match on anything. When I try something like:

```
grep -o '[0-9]'
```

it matches all the separate numbers, so 1 9 9 4 2 and 8.

So my syntax is wrong but as for as my knowledge goes this matches a number of 0 to 9 4 times, the {} specifying length either in a range or exact range. If someone could help me with this simple syntax it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `{4}` is an [*extended* regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions). `grep` will not understand it unless you specify the `-E` option:

```
-E, --extended-regexp
       Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)
```

try with

```
grep -E '[0-9]{4}'
```

example

```
$ echo abcd1234abcd | grep -o -E '[0-9]{4}'
1234
```

you can also use the `[:digit:]` character class to avoid problems with locales where the order of the symbols could be different:

```
$ echo abcd1234abcd | grep -o -E '[[:digit]]{4}'
1234
```

if for any reason you don't want to use extended regular expressions you can use

```
grep -o '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```